# takePicture failed error when trying to take a picture from Camera (expo)

Tags: react-native, camera, expo

I am trying to open the camera and taking a picture when clicking on some button but still having this error `[Error: takePicture failed]` without any error debugging information.

here is my code:

```
import { Camera, Permissions } from 'expo';

class SignUp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.openCamera = this.openCamera.bind(this);
   }

   async openCamera() {
        if (this.camera) {
        const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
        if(status === 'granted'){
          console.log('Taking photo granted');
          this.camera.takePictureAsync({ skipProcessing: true }).then(photo => {
            console.log('photo', photo);            
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('err', err); 
          });
        }
        else{
          console.log('no permission granted');
        }
      }
   }

   render() {
       return (
         <View>
            <Camera
                  ref={ (ref) => {this.camera = ref} }
                  type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
                  autoFocus={'off'}
            ></Camera>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.openCamera} >
                 <Text>open camera</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
         </View>
       )
   }
}
```

and I can't edit any native modules because it is an expo app

any help, please!

Comment: if(status === 'granted')

Comment: i tried, the same problem.

Comment: `await this.camera.takePictureAsync` Could you try this?